# "How could" vs "Why would"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I'm trying to finish off an essay on "why I want to be a ...." and I want to conclude saying that it is a wonderful opportunity.

1. .... so **how could** I say no this wonderful opportunity.
2. .... so **why would** I say no this wonderful opportunity.

What is the difference between the above 2? Which is most suitable for my need or is there something else that is more suitable?

Comment: They're both colloquial, just add a question mark at the end. They are rhetorical questions with obvious answers, but still questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"...so **how could** I say no" is the correct idiom. If you said "Why would I say no?", you are leaving open some room for doubt, whereas the first way is 100% certain.